# Tkinter: Error "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" when trying to remove widget from a list

Tags: python, tkinter

In my app I've create a frame, a text and a button widget thanks to a loop and stored them in a list to be able to work with them. Rigth now I'd like to create a delete button to remove `self.frame_2, self.text, self.canc_button`  from my main frame and also from the `self.loop_list`. When using `self.loop.remove(self.text)` (or I try to remove any kind of widget in this way) I'm getting this error:  `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`
This is my code right now, what am I doing wrong?

```
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true", side="bottom")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="true")
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mousewheel)    
    
        self.pop()


    def pop(self):    
        self.list = list(range(13))
        self.loop = []
     
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.list_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.list_frame, anchor="nw")

        for index, number in enumerate(self.list): 
            self.frame_2 = tk.Frame(self.list_frame)
            self.frame_2.pack(pady=(15,0), fill="x", expand="yes", side="top")

            self.text = tk.Text(self.frame_2, wrap="word", height=1)
            self.text.pack(padx=15, side="left")
       
            self.canc_button = tk.Button(self.frame_2, text="Cancel", command=lambda x=index: self.delete(x))
            self.canc_button.pack(side="right")

            self.loop.append((self.frame_2, self.text, self.canc_button))


    def delete(self, index):
        self.frame_2, self.text, self.canc_button = self.loop[index]

        self.loop.remove(self.text)
        self.loop.remove(self.canc_button)    

        self.text.destroy()
        self.canc_button.destroy()
```

Comment: Try `self.loop.pop(index)` to remove item at index. Also just call `self.frame_2.destroy()` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

you loop items are tuples, and not loose elements. you can't just remove a whole tuple by using a member like that, so the following

```
def delete(self, index):
        self.frame_2, self.text, self.canc_button = self.loop[index]

        self.loop.remove(self.text)
        self.loop.remove(self.canc_button)
```

would make more sense as

```
def delete(self, index):
        self.frame_2, self.text, self.canc_button = self.loop[index]

        self.loop.remove((self.frame_2, self.text, self.canc_button))
```

or as @acw1668 suggested:

```
def delete(self, index):
        self.frame_2, self.text, self.canc_button = self.loop.pop(index)
```

but that also removes what ever `self.frame_2` is (which should probably be destroyed).

Comment: Thank you! I've tried both ways and: when using the `pop.(index)` method after I delete "0", when I click the button linked to "1" it doesn't delete it, but the one that follow (2,3,4...); when using `remove()`  the first time when pressing a button nothing happens and the second time it gives me back the same ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: @itt Then it is better to use a dictionary instead of list.

Comment: How should I use a dictionary in this casa? I'm using this list in all my code and it would be troublesome changing it now. is there not a way to delete the correct item from the list?

Comment: If you remove one item from a list, the index of those items after the deleted item in the list will be changed.  That is why you delete wrong item.